# How to get from list from desired index number in vue.js?

Tags: list, vue.js, indexing, nuxt.js

I am getting data through api , in which i am fetching array of data into a list... I just want to import title from that list..
I stucked, everyone is using v-for loop for getting the data...i tried {{list[0].title}} but this shows me the error that title is undefined.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ke0o.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ke0o.png)

Comment: Please add your code into the question as text, so it will be easier for people to read it and help you. Also it's not clear what are you trying to achieve, what do you mean by 'importing' title from a list?

Comment: this error shows that there is no data in your List array. Try to console list in the response. after this.list = resp.data;  please console this.list and check data.

Comment: yeah, error resolved i just defined title in the props and the error vanished